# Get vector coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I'm currently working on a ray tracer, more specifically on ray-cylinder intersection. The cylinder is defined by a position (that I've called $coord$ and is the position vector of one of the caps, $cap1$), a height (which is a float) and an orientation (a vector of which its coordinates range from $-1.0$ to $1.0$). Based on this, I should define another cap, $cap2$.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTyuO.png) is a representation in 2D of what it should look like.
My issue is I can't quite figure out how to get the coordinates for the second cap. I've tried doing such things :
$cap2 = (orient + coord) * height$
 $cap2 = (orient + coord) - coord$
 or $cap2 = coord + (posit * height)$ without much success.
It should be noted that $orient$ and the vector going to $cap2$ are parallel.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a right circular cylinder in 3D is defined using the following properties:

- Cylinder base, $\vec{b}$.  This is the center of the circular disc at one end of the cylinder.
- Cylinder axis, $\vec{a}$.  This is the direction and length of the cylinder axis.  Sometimes the axis is split into an unit direction vector $\hat{a}$ ($\lVert \hat{a} \rVert = 1$) and height $h$, so that $\vec{a} = h \hat{a}$.
- Cylinder radius, $r$.

Since $\vec{b}$ is one end of the cylinder, the other end is at $\vec{b} + \vec{a} = \vec{b} + h \hat{a}$.

The volume enclosed by this cylinder consists of points $\vec{p}$ that fulfill
$$\left\lbrace \; \begin{aligned}
\left\lVert \hat{a} \times (\vec{p} - \vec{b}) \right\rVert & \le r \\
0 \le \hat{a} \cdot (\vec{p} - \vec{b}) &\le h \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where $\times$ denotes vector cross product, $\cdot$ denotes vector dot product, and $\lVert \; \rVert$ denotes Euclidean norm.